# Rebooted android phone and the Geolocation in my phonegap application stopped working

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, geolocation

I rebooted my android phone and the geolocation code in my app has stopped working. The `navigator.geolocation` is returning true but `getCurrentPosition` and `watchPosition` aren't working. It isn't returning an error message either. I have location turned on the phone, the phone version is 5.0.1 and the cordova version I am using is 5.3.3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The JavaScript code I am using:

```
function showCurrentPosition(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
}


// onSuccess Callback
// This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
// current GPS coordinates
//
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError() {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

Console Log:

```
The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.
file:///android_asset/www/css/images/ajax-loader.gif Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
whitelist.js:23 No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.(anonymous function) @ whitelist.js:23
index.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
521whitelist.js:25 No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.
```

Comment: you are going to have a much better chance of getting help if you include the errors that it is throwing in with your question. Can you go copy the stack trace and edit your question to include it?

Comment: @FoamyGuy I have updated the question and added in the console log from google chrome webview. I have got the sqlite database to work but I can't see what is stopping the geolocation from working though have you any idea? The system is recognizing that the plugin is there but the functions get and watch position won't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing my geolocation to stop working. When I rebooted my android is set the location services to GPS only. When I changed it use WiFi, phone network and GPS for my location it was able to obtain my longitude and latitude.

The problem with my android phone is that the GPS has stopped working so this turned out to be a hardware problem not a software problem.